# SQL & Excel - Storing excel functions in SQL

Tags: sql, excel

I am storing vlookups in a sql field. When I load it into excel:
**that code is showing up with a ' (single quote) in front of the code.**

Is it possible to store a function in a SQL field that will load into Excel without the ' (single quote) at the front of the string so that when opened in excel the function works?

Comment: Curious, why not run a query in place of vlookups and avoid storing any formulas?

Comment: Because queries in power query do not work well with password protected files and the data that I am trying to access is in a pw protected excel file.   Power query will however pull in the data if I use vlookups and have the pw protected file open - so wanted to use vlookups.  Instead of doing them every time I wanted to hard code them into a SQL field.

Answer (score 0):

A single quote as the first character in cell, forces text format for the column at the start of a cell is used to force text format. You may have your cells formatted as text.

You may also need to do Data-> Text to Columns-> Finish.

Also, try hitting 'Calculate Now' in the formulas tab.